# Save output of a Fabric command in a list, where each row is a list element

Tags: python, fabric

Is possible to get a list as output of a Fabric command?

Something like ls -la (but it could be any command), where each row is saved as an entry of a list; so I can cycle trough it later on:

```
mylist=[]
mylist=run('ls -la')

for each item in mylist:
    print item
```

As now, the output of the command is sent to the list, one char at time, resulting in something totally unmanageable.

I am using Fabric since I run these commands on a remote machine

Comment: If you just want the output of ls -la subprocess.check_output will work

Comment: Thanks, the ls -la is just an example; I may run different commands; that's why I am trying to not use subprocess.

Comment: subprocess can run pretty much any command

Comment: True, but for commands on remote machines, Fabric helps a lot

Comment: Unfortunately I have very little experience with fabric so hopefully someone else will help you out

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham; I was not very specific in my question, so I edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of "run" is actually a "string" (fabric.operations._AttributeString), you can use the rsplit method to split the output into the format of list

```
from fabric.api import *

mylist = run("ls -al").rsplit("\n")
for item in mylist:
    print item
```

However, the upper code uses the "\n" as the line separator, which could cover most of the cases, however, there are also some platforms which use "\r" as the line separator, which you need to handle carefully.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I will have to check the output then, to be sure that it will use the \n as newline.

Comment: `"ls -1" will output each file on a newline. That can be easy to use, especially if you are just looking for filenames.